# No DIVs created by D3 on enter() data with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, d3.js

*Please note that it's not a question on **how to** get a bar. I've got that covered, luckily. It's more of a **why not** issue. When the reality doesn't meet the expectation, there's usually a lesson to be learned. Also, based on the awesomely helpful comments, I realized that the diagnostics were incorrect so I updated the question.*

I've just started experimenting with D3. Following the examples, I get some nice graphs. Then, I tested this (just to accumulate knowledge on less usual approach with purely academic purpose).

```
var graphs = d3.select("#graph").selectAll("div");
graphs.data([1, 2, 3, 4]).enter()
  .append("div").text(function(d){ return d; });
```

The number of DIVs doesn't change. That confuses me, because I'd expect an increment by 4 (if I'm creating a DIV for each such element). When I [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/gnj43pbn/1/) the code, it works. However, I'm stuck on how to trouble-shoot it.

- I checked that *d3.select("#graph")* does contain precisely one element.
- I've run the script from the console to avoid load order issues.

My page is a partial view rendered by Razor. All other scripts, except jQuery, which I'need to keep as it's called on page load, are removed.

```
...
<div id="#graph" ...></div>
...
@section style{ @Styles.Render("~/Page.css") }
@section script{
  @Scripts.Render("~/Page.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/d3.min.js")
}
```

Comment: @Cyril There you go! It was a case of incorrect diagnostics on my part (due to lack of competence and excess of confusion regarding D3). Feel free to take a look.

Comment: "I checked that d3.select("#graph") does contain precisely one element."

Are you saying it returns an array of one element, or that the single member of that array actual contains a useful dom element?

If I type d3.select("#withisjfsdopafwdgdfgdfgkl") I get a result of array[1] returned, it's just that the dom element in that array is a null

Comment: Since the fiddle is OK, I want to see the markup of the page. Specifically the order of scripts loaded. And following up on @mgraham, what happens if you remove or rename the DIV with id `graph`?

Comment: No errors on the console?  Is your page public; can you link it?  Is the above `d3` code running from `Page.js`, shouldn't `d3.min.js` be loaded before it?  "I've run the script from the console to avoid load order issues" - that didn't work?

Comment: @Mark See my answer. I think you've got a good point but he tried that from the console **but** take a look at the `id`of his DIV. See?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three things in your code. First of all, using the selector `d3.("#graph")` refers to `<div id="graph" />`. You've got a sharp sign **in the id of the HTML**. That's why you don't see the number of elements increase - they're created into a different component. Use this, instead.

```
<div id="graph" ...>
```

An additional point's the order of your scripts. You markup is wrong because you read in `Page.js` before `d3.min.js`. If you're not getting errors because of lacking `d3` in the `onload` of your page (which I'm assuming is in the first one), then you've got multiple references to it. This one is unneeded because you've got a global one covering it. Or you can switch the order of scripts like this and skip the global one.

```
@section script{
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/d3.min.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Page.js")
}
```

Last point's about your sections. I'm assuming they're called from the layout and that this is only a partial view. If so, keep an eye on the order of rendering. Invoking the rendering of sections in partial views at different stages of the layout can create issues.

Comment: Good catch, that `id="#graph"` is probably the problem.

Comment: @Mark It's **one** of the problems. But as you saw yourself, the scripts weren't loaded in right order (although it's easy to think they are).